# Blockchain.info - generated addresses & the blockchain

Tags: blockchain, api, blockchain.info

I am generating new addresses with the blockchain api and sending funds to them from a primary blockchain.info address. Just wanted to know if those transactions will appear in the blockchain or are they internal to blockchain.info?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you send a small transaction and try it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all transactions to and from blockchain.info wallets will be recorded in the blockchain.  blockchain.info does not control their customers' private keys, making it impossible for them to perform offchain transactions.  In contrast, Coinbase uses internal accounting for transfers between Coinbase accounts.

Comment: I would be extremely cautious telling people that blockchain.info has no control. They can certainly see what the private key is when used by the API, and when used by the web view they can at any moment recover the private key. Pretending otherwise is their mantra.